# Centering address, every solution i find i have already tried

Tags: html, css, position, center

I am having a real issue that I am sure is just because I have not been coding for long, and easily overlook simple mistakes.
I am trying to centre an address, and have tried containing in in a div, or just formatting it on its own, but I cant get it to centre.
Please note, I wish for the address to stay fixed to the screen, so it does not move when scrolling.
Here's my code (I know everyone hates people pasting large sections of code, but I have yet to learn how to link my jsfiddle page)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet for real index.css">
</style>
    <head>
    <title>Test of notepad ++</title>
    </head>
        <body>
<div style="text-align: center;height: 100%;background: #4FD5D6;">
    <iframe src="index.html" scroll="no">Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
</div>
<div class="center">
    <address>
    Made by <em><b>Dantoon e</b></em><br>So look out
    </address>
</div>
</body>
```

And the css

```
body {
  font-family: Nobile;
  background-color: #4FD5D6;
  display: empty-cells;  }  
iframe {
  display: block !important;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: -1000px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;  }
.center  { 
  border-top: thick dotted;
  border-bottom: thick dotted;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;  
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 1204px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;  }
```

I only include the whole page as I don't know is a slip-up somewhere else may be effecting the address.  Thanks is advance!

Comment: if that's all it is I will kick myself

Comment: nope, still does not work, thanks for help though, cant believe I did that!

Comment: I didn't mean that as a solution, just a note. Shouldn't the width of your `.center` element be 100% instead of 1204px?

Comment: width: 100% causes the address to span the full width of the site, it should line up with the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an opening html tag and body is before the closer, plus have a random /style :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet for real index.css" />
        <title>Test of notepad ++</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;height: 100%;background: #4FD5D6;">
            <iframe src="index.html" scroll="no">Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
       </div>
       <div class="center">
           <address>
                Made by <em><b>Dantoon e</b></em><br>So look out
           </address>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With CSS:

```
.center {
    display: block;
    border-top: thick dotted;
    border-bottom: thick dotted;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a fiddle that works (br needs a trailing slash) too.  Plus I'd not fix things to 1200 px - use 100%
http://jsfiddle.net/QcSt9/1/

Comment: thanks for the help, but your code still did not work, I cant understand why (I only learnt what scc was around 3 weeks ago, and html around a month before!  So yea, my code is poor!) +I did not down vote

Comment: What browser are you using out of curiosity, the fiddle looks fine for me?

Comment: and the stuff on fiddle works, but when I copy across any changes, it wont work, so I think it must be issue further up, rather than with the address its self

Comment: Okey dokey, give me a second I'll update my answer with the full html

Comment: the html tags where removed when I posted the question for some reason, but the random /style was there!  thanks

Comment: although it still wont centre

Comment: I've just updated the .center CSS in the hope this might help.  Is any of the address centered or is it all left aligned?

Comment: thanks you so much, I think my problem was a combination of random tags and small errors that led to the issue!

Comment: Not a problem - glad you've managed to solve it :D  It's actually really easy to get odd bits wrong and be completely blind to them - generally somebody looking from the outside will spot them in seconds...

Comment: ha, looking back on old questions, i realise how bad i was :) I made just about every error possible, even had inline styles conflicting with CSS!

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is some changes to this:

Add a Container/Parent div that will contain inside your child divs of the iframe and center class div:

```
<div class="container">
    <iframe></iframe>
     <div class="center">
        <address>blah</address>
     </div>     
</div>
```

That container will have a class position relative....then you can absolute your senter class to be at bottom and centered based on the containers width that you gave the iframe (1200px)

Here is the:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/KZ4F4/)

Comment: thanks for the help, but the iframe was not the issue, although I have taken your advice and added a parent div, just to help with formatting

Comment: np. glad i could help you in some way

Answer (score 1):

Also, not sure if you notised, but your stylesheet link is outside the head, you have a useless stlye closer and used inline styles (not wrong, but not recomended ether)

Hope this helps :)